# std::get_time fails at midnight or noon using %I format specifier

Tags: c++11, visual-c++

When using `std::get_time`, I get an exception when parsing a `datetime` at midnight or noon. I am using the `%I` format specifier instead of `%H` because the hour should be between 1-12.

> Exception: "ios_base::failbit set: iostream stream error"

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2013.

Why am I getting an exception when parsing this datetime? Is there a different format mask I can use?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstring>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::time_t time;
    std::string timeString = "1/5/15 12:00 AM";
    std::string formatMask = "%m/%d/%y %I:%M %p";

    std::tm tm;
    std::memset(&tm, 0, sizeof(std::tm));
    std::istringstream ss(timeString);
    ss.exceptions(std::ios::failbit | std::ios::badbit);

    try
    {
        ss >> std::get_time(&tm, formatMask.c_str());
        time = std::mktime(&tm);
    }
    catch (const std::exception& ex)
    {
        std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << time << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is the exception you get a secret?

Comment: question: is there a reason why you think a `memset` to zero `std::tm` is a valid one?  Looking [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/tm), that means you say it is midnight Sun Jan 0th, 1900, the 1st day of the year, with DST not in effect.  Not only is this inconsistent, it also includes at least one value that is "out of gamut" (0th day of a month).  There may be other side effects from `memset`ing a `std::tm` (I do not recall if it is guaranteed to be trivially copyable standard layout struct).  Getting `localtime`, then setting h/m/s to zero, would at least be defined behavior.

Comment: @Yakk the tm parameter is an output of get_time, not an input.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, added the exception

Comment: @JordanBean what locale are you trying to parse this in?

Comment: If I don't memset the std::tm to zero to start with, I get garbage in the struct (especially in debug mode) which later messes up the datetime

Comment: @NulledPointer Locale is LC_ALL: English_United States.1252

Comment: Quick comment: Use zero initializers intead of `memset` ie `std::tm tm = std::tm();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ios_base::failbit` generally means some logical error has occurred in processing the `istringstream`. Checking description of [%I format](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time) it seems that the range seems wrongly specified here, it should be `range [00,11]` for a 12 hour clock IMO.

It should ideally work for 00:00 through 11:59 with Visual Studio 2013 compiler.

Thanks to @Cubbi [posix specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strptime.html) does specify the range to be `range [01,12]` but so does [MSVS2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fe06s4ak.aspx).

The MSDN documentation for [time_get::do_get](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee428022(v=vs.100).aspx) specifies the range to be `range[00,11]` and this seems to be what `std::get_time` uses in VS2013 (@Cubbi found this).

Comment: The description for %I says "parses hour as a decimal number, 12 hour clock (range [01,12]), leading zeroes permitted but not required"

Comment: Exactly and i think this specification is incorrect. My claim is that range should be 00,11. For a 12 hour clock time starts with 00:00 and ends at 11:59

Comment: Hmmm, you may be right, I tried using 00:00 instead and that worked

Comment: The specification is actually 01-12, in Posix, to which the C++ standard refers for this

Comment: ..taking a look at MSDN, they actually document this as 0-11. No wonder OP code works as expected everywhere except visual studio

Comment: @Cubbi which document is it exactly?

Comment: If I weren't on a phone, I'd post links. Btw, MS fixed %I in 2015, per bug 808162 (although I don't have the RC to check what was fixed)

Comment: ..and your ms link is to strftime, which isn't directly relevant. See time_get::do_get on msdn for the 0-11 range.

Comment: "it should be range [00,11]". "For a 12 hour clock time starts with 00:00 and ends at 11:59". I have never met a person who would say "it's half past zero", or seen a 12-hour digital clock that would display 0 hours. And an analogue clock face has 12 at the top, not 0.